# How to get a fragment using position from a FragmentStateAdapter with ViewPager2

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-viewpager2, fragmentstatepageradapter

I am using `ViewPager2` with `FragmentStateAdapter` to create a collection of fragments. I want to access a particular fragment on the basis of its position in the Adapter. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get fragments by Ids using Fragment manager's [`findFragmentByTag("f$id")`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentManager#findFragmentByTag(java.lang.String))

But to do that you need to override `getItemId()` in the `FragmentStateAdapter` to return the position, so that the id now equals to the position.

```
override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
    return position.toLong()
}
```

Then to get a fragment at a position:

- If the `ViewPager2` is hosted by an activity use `supportFragmentManager`:

```
    fun getPageFragment(id: Long): Fragment? {
        return supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f$id")
    }
```

- And if it's hosted by a fragment use `childFragmentManager`:

```
    fun getPageFragment(id: Long): Fragment? {
        return childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("f$id")
    }
```